# How to stop the slideshow

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i am using jbgallery slideshow(http://maxb.net/scripts/jbgallery/) for one of our projects.

Can you please let me know how to stop the slideshow when a user clicks on the prev & next buttons. We have an automatic slideshow, but when user clicks on either button the automatic sliding should stop.

Comment: would you please share the code in your question.

Comment: @Saifuddin here is the link: http://bit.ly/trksxZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear the developer coded any real callbacks for his buttons.  Using [Firebug for Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/) (or another DOM inspector) you can get the class names of his elements and accomplish what you want with the info like so.

```
var obj = $("#jbgallery-api").jbgallery({
    menu: "slider",
    slideshow: "true"
}, true);  // true parameter = return jbgallery object (for use to stop later)

// .jbgs-h-prev = prev button class, .jbgs-h-next = next button class
$('.jbgs-h-prev, .jbgs-h-next').click(function() {  // onClick event handler
    obj.stop();  // Stop the slideshow

    // Using obj.stop() doesn't reset the state of the play/pause button
    // so we need to hide the pause button and show the play button.
    $('.jbgs-h-pause').hide();
    $('.jbgs-h-play').show();
});
```

Fiddle Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/5sXDS/

Comment: True. Try to play with the prev/next on the top-bar. The buttons are there only for admiration... it looks. Useless.

Comment: @Jeff Wilbert: here is our demo http://bit.ly/trksxZ, can you please suggest me at here...

Comment: @Jeff Wilbert: thank you it worked by writing ,true and obj.stop thank you much...